# Override serializer delete method in Django RF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer that inherits from the django rest framework serializer `ModelSerializer`.

To overwrite the create method, I can redefine `create`. To redefine the update method, I redefine `update`. I'm looking through the code though and can't find the method to overwrite for deletion. I need to do this in the serializer so I can grab the deleting user.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're using a ModelViewSet, you could do it in the view:

```
class YourViewSetClass(ModelViewSet):

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       user = request.user # deleting user
       # you custom logic # 
       return super(YourViewSetClass, self).destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The destroy method is so simple (just a call to instance.delete()) that the action is not delegated to the serializer. The serializers in DRF are for negotiating external representations to/from your database models. Here you simply want to delete a model.

Comment: Ah perfect, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 12):

I think you can do that but in the view level.

So if you're using ModelViewsets you can override the [destory method](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)  or the [`perform_destroy`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L87) and add your business logic.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `perform_destroy` is intended as a hook to override delete behavior.