# Delete operation using Serializes

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In official document [serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#creating-a-serializer-class) class show only create & update method only. There is any way to perform delete method? is say Yes how? if say No why?

Comment: you can see more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209878/override-serializer-delete-method-in-django-rf

Comment: without modelset their any possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the source code of serializer. https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py

As you can see there is no delete. I think the reason is because there is nothing to serialize/deserialze when you make a deletion request.

Think about the what it means by serialization and deserialization. It's a process of turning object in memory to a string representation (or the other way around). When we make a request to delete /Foo/5, there's no string representation nothing to deserialize.

If you want custom behavior during deletion you can override delete() in viewset.